# How to update a package from github when it was installed using apt-get and latest version not available in the deb repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, git

I want to update a package that was installed from the debian repository but the latest version is only available in a git repo. How can I go about updating the package?

Comment: Security fixes only get backported to older versions; with newer versions only replacing the Ubuntu repository package IF it's more work to backport fixes, then provide new version with all required QA/testing etc.. When this occurs it's blogged about in warning; as Ubuntu aims to be a *stable* system  (*refer notices on this occurring with the 20.04 release etc; you didn't provide any OS/release details though*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to remove the package installed from the repository, then install the package from the git repo according to the instructions of that package. From that point on, you took the maintenance of that software in your own hands. It will not be automatically updated.